# jQuery Right-Click Context Menu Help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, contextmenu

http://pastebin.com/YyDzQ4Bk this is a plugin for right click context menu, anyone know why it doesn't work in IE?

Not only that, it's breaking many of my other jQuery things, such as fancy box and some jQuery hover functions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you really need a plugin?

You could make your own context menu using `contextmenu` event:

```
$("element").bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // create and show menu
});
```

Some ways to achieve it

- [jQuery Context Menu script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/contextmenu.htm)
- [Create a jQuery Context Menu for Treeview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/jQueryContextMenu.aspx)
- [Right or Left Click Context Menu Using jQuery Demo](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/11/04/Right-or-Left-Click-Context-Menu-Using-jQuery-Demo.aspx)

Comment: Create a `ul`, `li` s. Append `li` to `ul` and append on the page. Set `ul` position to absolute, left and top with `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`. I will update my answers with some links.

Comment: if the element is created dinamicy you need to use live instead of bind

Comment: now you should use .on if your element is created dynamically see: http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/