# Control Based context menu using JQuery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to implement a control based(image,button etc) context menu using JQuery in an asp.net webpage?

Comment: Please add some code here what you have tried?

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996204/jquery-right-click-context-menu-help (Menu can be a jQueryUI one : http://jqueryui.com/menu/#icons)

Comment: @BhaveshKachadiya: will add the code

Comment: @JamesS:Will go through those links and try them out!Thanks